# Change color and legend of plotLearnerPrediction ggplot2 object

Tags: colors, legend, mlr

I've been producing a number of nice plots with the plotLearnerPrediction function in the mlr package for R. They look like [this](https://mlr-org.github.io/Visualisation-of-predictions/). From looking into the source code of the plotLearnerPrediction function it looks like the color surfaces are made with geom_tile.
A plot can for example be made by:

```
library(mlr)
data(iris)

#make a learner
lrn <- "classif.qda"
#make a task
my.task <- makeClassifTask(data = iris, target = "Species")
#make plot
plotLearnerPrediction(learner = lrn, task = my.task)
```

Now I wish to change the colors, using another red, blue and green tone to match those of some other plots that I've made for a project. for this I tried `scale_fill_continuous` and `scale_fill_manual` without any luck (Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale) I also wish to change the legend title and the labels for each legend entry (Which I tried giving appropriate parameters to the above `scale_fill`'s). There's a lot of info out there on how to set the geom_tile colours when producing the plot, but I haven't found any info on how to do this post-production (i.e. in somebody else's plot object). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `plotLearnerPrediction` returns the ggplot2 object, so you should be able to change those things. Can you post a complete example of what doesn't work please?

Comment: It's not that I complain about stuff not working, I just don't know how to change the colors and other stuff as outlined above. If you run the code above, you get a plot that looks like the one in the link. Given you have such a plot how would you change the colors, legend title and legend labels?

Comment: You can modify some of these things through `theme()`, e.g. `p = plotLearnerPrediction(...); p + theme(legend.position = "top")`, but not everything can be customised this way. For some things you'll have to modify the source code.

Answer (score 0):

When you look into the [source code](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/blob/1e18c3fa2b4be8f29efc6448a4b3dc4698928528/R/plotLearnerPrediction.R#L169) you see how the plot is generated and then you can see which scale has to be overwritten or set.

In this example it's fairly easy:

```
g = plotLearnerPrediction(learner = lrn, task = my.task)
library(ggplot2)
g + scale_fill_manual(values = c(setosa = "yellow", versicolor = "blue", virginica = "red"))
```

[image]