# change color data points plotLearnerPrediction (MLR package)

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, mlr

I have produced some nice plots with the plotLearnerPrediction function of the MLR package. I was able to make some adjustments to the returned ggplot (see my code below). But I am not sure how to make the last adjustment. Namely, I want to change the coloring of the data points based on labels (groups in example plot).

[My last plot (with black data points)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZhi2.png)

[Another produced plot (overlapping data points)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVNev.png)

This is the last version of my code (normally part of a for loop):

```
plot <- plotLearnerPrediction(learner = learner_name, task = tasks[[i]], cv = 0,
                              pointsize = 1.5, gridsize = 500) + 
  ggtitle(trimws(sprintf("Predictions %s %s", meta$name[i], meta$nr[i])), 
          subtitle = sprintf("DR = %s, ML = %s, CV =  LOO, ACC = %.2f", meta$type[i], 
                             toupper(strsplit(learner_name, "classif.")[[1]][2]), acc[[i]])) + 
  xlab(sprintf("%s 1", lab)) + 
  ylab(sprintf("%s 2", lab)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 18, face = "bold"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold", colour = "grey40"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = 0.5),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"),
        #panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
        axis.line.x = element_line(color = "black", size = 1),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color = "black", size = 1),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        legend.justification = "top",
        legend.margin = margin(l = 0),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 14))
```

Below is a part of the source code of the plotLearnerPrediction function. I want to overrule geom_point(colour = "black"). Adding simply geom_point(colour = "pink") to my code will not color data points, but the whole plot. Is there a solution to overrule that code with a vector of colors? Possibly a change in the aes() is also needed to change colors based on groups.

```
        else if (taskdim == 2L) {
        p = ggplot(mapping = aes_string(x = x1n, y = x2n))
        p = p + geom_tile(data = grid, mapping = aes_string(fill = target))
        p = p + scale_fill_gradient2(low = bg.cols[1L], mid = bg.cols[2L], 
            high = bg.cols[3L], space = "Lab")
        p = p + geom_point(data = data, mapping = aes_string(x = x1n, 
            y = x2n, colour = target), size = pointsize)
        p = p + geom_point(data = data, mapping = aes_string(x = x1n, 
            y = x2n), size = pointsize, colour = "black", 
            shape = 1)
        p = p + scale_colour_gradient2(low = bg.cols[1L], 
            mid = bg.cols[2L], high = bg.cols[3L], space = "Lab")
        p = p + guides(colour = FALSE)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always hack into gg objects. The following works for ggplot2 2.2.1 and adds a manual alpha value to all geom_point layers.

```
library(mlr)
library(ggplot2)
g = plotLearnerPrediction(makeLearner("classif.qda"), iris.task)
ids.geom.point = which(sapply(g$layers, function(z) class(z$geom)[[1]]) == "GeomPoint")
for(i in ids.geom.point) {
  g$layers[[i]]$aes_params$alpha = 0.1
}
g
```

Comment: This is really cool!! Is it also possible to set the alpha per point? I am using a Gaussian Mixture Model which returns a responsibilty per point. If I can express these reponsibilities in alpha levels, that would be perfect. Another point is that I am really curious in changing the color of data points based on cluster. For instance, change all setosa species data points into pink. If you can help me with this you will be my hero!

Comment: Then you would be back at wanting to use the aesthetics. I think it is easier to modify these in the source of the plotting function.

Comment: Tnx! I started already changing the source code. I will put my solution online when I am finished.

Answer (score 0):

The `plotLearnerPrediction()` function returns the `ggplot` plot object, which allows for some level of customization without having to modify the source code. In your particular case, you can use `scale_fill_manual()` to set custom fill colors:

```
library(mlr)
g = plotLearnerPrediction(makeLearner("classif.randomForest"), iris.task)
g + scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow", "orange", "red"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are you reffering to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45755867/change-color-and-legend-of-plotlearnerprediction-ggplot2-object
This will only change the colour of the grid and is already used in my code. Or am I missing something?

Comment: So what exactly do you want the plot to look like?

Comment: I added a second example plot to my original question to make the problem more clear. If you have a look at that you can see that data points are overlapping. Because they are all black the plot is not really clear, therefore I want to change the color of the data points. Each cluster will get the same color, which hopefully helps in better distinghuising the data points.

Comment: Ah, for this you actually do need to change the code I think. You'd need to put something like `color = class` in the `aes` for `geom_point()`. That said, I don't think that this will make the plot more readable. Have you considered transparency instead?